# Lambda Equivalent of Method reference throws error

Tags: java, lambda

I am trying some lambda code snippets to learn. When I pass method reference the code works fine , but as soon as I pass lambda equivalent it throws error.

I tried to sort a list using comparing of Comparator class passing lambda which throws error. The same code works fine when i pass method reference.
Transation::getValue works fine but transaction-> transaction.getValue() doesn't work.

```
public class Trader {
    private final String name;
    private final String city;

    public Trader(String n, String c) {
        this.name = n;
        this.city = c;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return this.city;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Trader:" + this.name + " in " + this.city;
    }
}

public class Transaction {

    private final Trader trader;
    private final int year;
    private final int value;

    public Transaction(Trader trader, int year, int value) {
        this.trader = trader;
        this.year = year;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Trader getTrader() {
        return this.trader;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return this.year;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "{" + this.trader + ", " + "year: " + this.year + ", " + "value:" + this.value + "}";
    }
}

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class TraderRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Trader raoul = new Trader("Raoul", "Cambridge");
        Trader mario = new Trader("Mario","Milan");
        Trader alan = new Trader("Alan","Cambridge");
        Trader brian = new Trader("Brian","Cambridge");

        List<Transaction> transactions = Arrays.asList(
                new Transaction(brian, 2011, 300),
                new Transaction(raoul, 2012, 1000),
                new Transaction(raoul, 2011, 400),
                new Transaction(mario, 2012, 710),
                new Transaction(mario, 2012, 700),
                new Transaction(alan, 2012, 950)
                );

        List<Transaction> list = transactions.stream()
                .filter(a -> a.getYear()== 2012).
                sorted(Comparator.comparing(Transaction::getValue)).
                collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: any response on this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It works for me